# Color box in front of the hex number and color name is not appeared

Tags: colorbox

Hi I need help for this error. I don't what i did as a mistake but i was writing code in css and then small preview of color box in front of the hex number and color name is not appeared anymore.
Did someone encounter this error before.

I uninstall every extension and I also clear the user setting.json but still error is persist.
i want to know how to solve thie error and also i want to know how to reset factory default in vscode or start from fresh in vscode. I can make new profile and it show the small box infront of the hex number and color name but it didn't show in default profile.